# Rails: identifying type of model in joined collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I make an array of records like so:

```
@records = Tapes.all + Discs.all
```

How can I identify which is which in the view and write code accordingly? Something like this is what I'm after:

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
  <%= record.side if record.type => :tape %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `object.class`, or `object.is_a?`. Something like following:

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
  <%= record.side if record.class == Tape %>
<% end %>
```

Or,

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
  <%= record.side if record.is_a?(Tape) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ah, the simple things, eh? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

May be a better approach for this is to define a method on both objects that will provide you the expect data:

```
class Tapes
  def quack
    self.side
  end
  ...
end

class Discs
  def quack
    # self.something
  end
  ...
end
```

Then in your template:

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
  <%= record.quack %>
<% end %>
```